# Start the same (or similar) Jenkins job without waiting for old one to finish on a gerrit trigger

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

Sorry if my title isn't clear. I have setup jenkins jobs for a few months now but no pipleline / workflow jobs and nothing too complicated yet.

I have a setup where I run builds in parallel once a change gets a CR+2 in gerrit and when the builds are successful and gets a V+1 the developer can submit the change. 
Now I need to add job with a call to a cli which submits a test to the test infrastructure and polls it (takes an hour or more) which should also be part of the V+1 verdict.
The requirement is the gerrit trigger should trigger the job for a new change submitted without waiting for the previous one. How do I achieve this? 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What I was looking for can be achieved by "Execute concurrent builds if necessary". It is in the basic job configuration, I was too new and hadn't explored this option as our regular requirement was to run the builds in sequence queue the builds to the same job.